# Richfaces packed.css and packed.jar not being created

Tags: richfaces

Working on a migration project for richfaces in Jboss EAP 6.4. Somewhat new to Richfaces but it seems that when I build the war richfaces should be creating a packed.css and a packed. jar file but neither of these are being created. I can not find anything online about having to enable this in web.xml wondering if anyone else has run across this issue. Here is my pom and components.xml files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I am an idiot. Our template had `<head>` tags when they needed to be `<h:head>` tags